# Why didn't Bane raid Wayne Manor after taking charge of Gotham?

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises

Why didn't Bane raid Wayne Manor after taking charge of Gotham in *The Dark Knight Rises*? We see him getting his hands on all of Batman's toys and gadgets. If he knew Bruce Wayne was Batman, why didn't he go back and check where he lived?

Also curious about Miranda's behavior, the house her father burned down, I expected her to prod more into Wayne Manor.

[image: car leaving Wayne Manor]

Comment: Is Wayne Manor on the same island as Gotham City? Remember that the federal government cuts off the only tunnel and bridge leading to the city.

Comment: Doesn't Blake visit Wayne Manor after the tunnel blasts, looking for Batman?

Comment: It might’ve been on the island. Or it’s a peninsula, although if that was the case people would just walk out of the city over the days Bane occupied it. Either the island is massive (Wayne Manor appears to be a ways outside of the city), or there’s something we’re missing....

Answer (score 5):

From Wikipedia, [Wayne Manor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Manor) is depicted in earlier comics as being on the outskirts of Gotham City in the state of New Jersey. Comic book portrayals place the mansion within driving distance of Gotham City, close enough that the batsignal can be seen from Wayne Manor alerting Batman of distress in the city.

Well, we don't really know why he didn't raid Wayne Manor. Some possibilities would be:

1. Miranda's Dad burnt down the place, so any old stuff at Wayne Manor is already destroyed anyway. Any new stuff may not be of much interest or value to people planning to end their lives in an exploding city.
2. Bane had already captured Bruce and would not have expected a batcave under Wayne Manor because he'd have assumed the armoury in the city was Batman's storage area.
3. The building is on the outskirts. Bane's primary work managing a lot of unruly people, is in the city. Yes, he could have visited Wayne Manor, but for a commander of his calibre, rummaging through somebody's house may not have been as much "fun" as breaking a plane into two or raiding a stock market or freeing prisoners. He could have sent someone to do the rummaging, but what would he get out of it? He didn't even find Bruce's other hideout in the city (where Bruce conducts experiments on bullet shattering). Bane has a larger plan: to destroy the city within a limited amount of time and before the patience of his people run out (remember his man in the broken plane asking if his sacrificing his life won't go in vain?). So Bane can't afford to waste time in side-quests.